# How could Sir Rupert see the ghost?

Tags: lockwood-and-co

In *The Empty Grave*, Marissa’s enforcer Sir Rupert seems to be able to see a ghost reacting to Lucy’s presence:

> “No, no. We’ll take it as read this time.” Sir Rupert raised his glass
> to the bloodstained ghost in the pillar, which was inching around to
> follow us as we walked past toward the door. “Looks as if someone
> likes you, anyway, Miss Carlyle. Isn’t it nice to have a fan?”
>
> “Didn’t
> know you could see ghosts so clearly, Sir Rupert,” Lockwood said.
> “Aren’t you a bit old for that?”
>
> An expression of mild annoyance crossed the man’s face, as of one
> caught in some minor indiscretion. “Oh, well,” he said. “I’m younger
> than I look. The doors are just through here….”
>
> <sub>*The Empty Grave*</sub>

Despite his assertion, he certainly *is* too old to see ghosts clearly. Now, he could be using the goggles that the Orpheus Society produced to allow one to see ghosts, but I feel that it would have been mentioned had he had a pair of enormous goggles strapped to his face (not something he’d likely do with secret technology at a fancy party, in any case).

How does he manage this feat of seeing ghosts?