# Why did Lucy’s powers expand?

Tags: lockwood-and-co

In *The Hollow Boy*, Lucy says that her Talent is growing stronger:

> “I do know that,” I said. “But I started it, and it was my anger that
> mostly fueled its power. No, sorry, George”—he’d tried to interrupt—“I
> am quite sure about this. It’s my Talent that did it. It’s getting
> stronger, and it’s getting harder to deal with, too. When it stirred
> up the Poltergeist it was working completely negatively, but even when
> I’m more in control—when I’m talking to ghosts, or listening to them
> talk—I’m sort of not in control anymore.
>
> <sub>*The Hollow Boy*</sub>

And indeed this seems to be the case, with her tending to be more susceptible to ghostly influence and hearing the thoughts of an ever greater variety of ghosts.

The thing is, that’s *not how it works*. More or less without exception, psychic Talents disappear by early adulthood—it’s why children are employed by agencies in such large numbers. The only exceptions are people who employ the ghost goggles (which are artificial), Sir Rupert ([not sure what’s going on there](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/169685/51379)), and Marissa Fittes (but she’s just a ghost possessing a human body).

Now, perhaps Lucy’s just an exception, but is there something else going on here?